# Can I use part of the implementation to build test expectation?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, integration-testing

Let's suppose that I use `build_help_message` many times throughout my application and it returns a big dictionary which contains `text` and `attachments` which I need to send using `Client` library.

Is it okay to use `build_help_message` to build expected result in the test? How can I avoid doing that, if it's not a good practice?

```
def help_handler(payload):
    team_id = payload['team_id']
    user_id = payload['user_id']

    message = build_help_message(team_id, user_id)

    Client(team_id).send_message(user_id, **message)
```

Tests

```
class TestHandler(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        team = Team.objects.create(team_id='TEAMID')
        User.objects.create(team=team, user_id='USERID')

    def tearDown(self):
        ...

    @mock.patch('client.Client.send_message')
    def test_correct_text(self, send_message_mock):
        payload = {'team_id': 'TEAMID', 'user_id': 'USERID'}

        handle_message(payload)

        expected_message = build_help_message('TEAMID', 'USERID')

        send_message_mock.assert_called_with('USERID', **expected_message)
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with django itself (tag removed), and barely anything to do with python - you'd have the very same question with just any language / techno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, reimplementing `build_help_message` in your test is certainly not better. What you *could* do (and what unittest purists might recommand here) would be to rewrite `help_handler` so you can inject the `build_message` dependency, ie:

```
def help_handler(payload, build_help_message=build_help_message):
    team_id = payload['team_id']
    user_id = payload['user_id']

    message = build_help_message(team_id, user_id)

    Client(team_id).send_message(user_id, **message)
```

and then mock `build_message` too - but unittest purists would also want you to do the same with `Client` (instead of using `Mock`) anyway.

Now while dependencies injection is a very powerful solution to some problems and something that every developper should know, applying it just everywhere in the name of "testability" is most often than not a waste of time wrt/ the benefit - at least when the language is dynamic enough to support monkeypatching of course - and doesn't necessarily help wrt/ readability either.

For your example, as far as I'm concerned and without more context (it's alway difficult to make an informed decision without knowing the project), I really wouldn't bother doing anything more - except of course unittesting `build_help_message` too but I assume this is already the case ;-)